# Why does my async function appear very clunky in my React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a set of images which my React component sequences through to create an animation effect by changing the opacity of each image every 50ms. The function works, however it appears to be a little jittery, despite all images being preloaded.

How can I make the function and overall 'animation' smoother?

```
class ProductView extends React.Component {

  static contextType = ChoicesContext;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      seq: null,
      open: null
    };

    this.forwardSequence = this.forwardSequence.bind(this);
    this.reverseSequence = this.reverseSequence.bind(this);
  }

  async sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
  }

  async forwardSequence(sequence, effect, id) {
    Array.prototype.reduce.call
    ( sequence
    , (r, img) => r.then(_ => this.sleep(50)).then(_ => effect(img))
    , Promise.resolve()
    )

    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open,
      seq: id
    });
  }

  async reverseSequence(sequence, effect) {
    Array.prototype.reduceRight.call
    ( sequence
    , (r, img) => r.then(_ => this.sleep(50)).then(_ => effect(img))
    , Promise.resolve()
    )

    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open,
      seq: null
    });
  }

  render() {
    const seq = document.getElementsByClassName("sequenceImage");

    return (
      <>

        <div className="productInteractive wrapper">
          {CurrentProduct.map((item, i) => (
            <main key={i} className={item.slug}>

              <div className="imageSequence">
                <SequenceImages />
              </div>

              <button
                  onClick={() => this.forwardSequence(seq, img => img.style.opacity = 1)}
                >Start Sequence</button>

            </main>
          ))}

        </div>

      </>
    );
  }
}
export default ProductView;
```

Comment: first thing, you dont not require async in all function. unless you are not using `await`

Comment: better use `css transition`